# Duda sobre diseño responsivo en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

Digamos que estoy trabajando con cuatro carpetas distintas para diferentes tamaños de pantalla. Estas carpetas son layout-sw320dp, layout-sw480dp, layout-sw600dp, layout-720dp.

Lo que no tengo claro es, hay que hacer modificaciones en el código de los layouts para cada uno de los directorios anteriores, o simplemente sería copiar y pegar el mismo código en cada uno de esos directorios?

Mi duda principal sería sobre todo como gestionar el alto y ancho de las distintas vistas de cada layout...
Tendría que darle yo un ancho y alto específicos para cada uno de los directorios sw
o limitarme a asignar "wrap_content" al height y width de las vistas en los distintos directorios sw sin importar el tamaño de pantalla mínimo?

Aquí un ejemplo de la duda que tengo entre dos opciones:

OPCIÓN 1:

layout-sw480dp

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp" />
```

layout-sw600dp

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="141dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp" />
```

layout-sw720dp:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="590dp"
        android:layout_height="103dp" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="247dp"
        android:layout_height="84dp" />
```

---

OPCION 2:

layout-sw480dp:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

layout-sw600dp:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

layout-720dp:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Mi duda es, cuál de las 2 opciones sería la correcta a la hora de aplicar un diseño responsivo?

Comment: No deberías copiar y pegar lo mismo. Estarías duplicando código innecesariamente. Si quieres que todo sea en base al mismo archivo, ubicalo en la carpeta `layout` a secas. Tal vez esto te interese https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout?hl=es-419 https://stackoverflow.com/a/30227274

Answer (score 1):

No es recomendable definir layout que contengan vistas con medidas fijas si tu objetivo es que tu app sea responsiva.

Si deseas usar directorios layout para diferentes densidades o tamaño, esto sería de utilidad si mostraras un layout diferente dependiendo del tamaño de tu dispositivo, por ejemplo:

[image: jorgesys layout handset android]

La solución sería usar `"wrap_content"` (Opción 2), para definir el ancho y alto de las vistas, ya que de esta forma permites que el mismo sistema operativo defina el tamaño de las vistas de acuerdo a su contenido, obteniendo un diseño responsivo. En este caso no necesitas definir el mismo layout en los directorios `/layout` de distintas densidades, simplemente define un único layout.

Comment: Ya he empezado a usar "wrap_content" para definir el alto y ancho de los Buttons y los Textview.... pero por ejemplo para los Editext utilizo unas medidas específicas en dp en función del tamaño de pantalla con el que esté trabajando (no sé si en este caso estoy haciendo lo correcto o también recomiendas usar "wrap_content". Entonces, aplicarías "wrap_content" a todos los tipos de vistas o sólo para unos tipos sí y para otros no?

Comment: Cuando usar o no wrap_content depende principalmente del diseño, comentas que usas dp para definir el tamaño de EditTexts, definir medidas en dp es requerido cuando tienes un diseño específico, te sugiero revisar el documento https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/migrate-to-responsive-layouts?hl=es-419

Answer (score 0):

Disculpar las molestias, ahora me ha surgido otro problema y me gustaría aprovechar este hilo....
He creado una carpeta layout-land donde he guardado los diseños de mis layouts específicos para la versión landscape.... El problema es que cuando instalo la aplicación en mi teléfono, al girar la pantalla, me sigue mostrando los mismos layouts que para la versión portrait, como si no me reconociera los diseños de la carpeta layout-land.....

Y también decir que he comprobado que mi teléfono sí detecta los cambios de orientación de pantalla, cuando la pantalla está en vertical la app muestra un toast que dice "Portrait" mientras cuando está en horizontal muestra un toast "Landscape", quiere decir mi movil detecta los cambios de orientación pero sin embargo en landscape no aplica los diseños de mi carpeta layout-land, y eso es lo que me tiene desconcertado.

Y aparte de mi teléfono personal también he probado la app en 3 emuladores distintos de mi Android Studio (2 con API 30 y el otro con API 29) y sigo teniendo también el mismo problema con todos ellos.... quiero decir, lo de que pueda ser problema específico de mi teléfono Samsung queda descartado, pues en los emuladores también me pasa lo mismo.

Vamos, ahora mismo estoy perdido y no sé qué más probar o qué puede estar fallando..